pairplot, continuous data - legend issue

Hello everybody,
I have a pairplot with continuous values, it render nice except for the legend.
The original legend has 43 different values, so I get 43 lines (mean rating on right).
I also tried to manually add a legend, but I can't get correctly the colors
Is their a way to avoid creating a new df grouping the values ?
I will then lose of granularity / detail
Please find my code, any help / clue will be greatly appreciated ...  :
Cheers
custom_palette = sns.blend_palette(['red', 'yellow', 'green'], n_colors=43)

pairplot = sns.pairplot (
    rates[cols_to_plot],
    hue = 'mean_rating',
    palette = custom_palette, # 'husl',
    corner = True
    )


Seaborn pairplots with continuous hues suggests diag_kws=dict(color=".2", hue=None).
